Quelle est la fonction de "de" ici ?
Dans les trois phrases suivantes, quelle est la fonction de "de" ?
Je vous fais part de ce que j'en pense. N’hésitez pas à me corriger.
L’expansion des commerces futiles. - Article indéfini pluriel
L’expansion de futiles commerces. - "De" remplace l'article indéfini suivi d'un adjectif.
L’expansion de commerces futiles. - "De" est préposition et introduit un complément du nom.
Si leur emploi correspond aux explications que j'en ai données, quelle est la différence de sens entre les phrases 1 et 3, la troisième me semblant aussi connoter une valeur partitive ?
Merci de vos réponses !
Il se peut qu'elles introduisent l'appartenance. Dans ce cas resterait encore le doute sur les différences de sens soulevé dans la deuxième question.

Sans plus de contexte, je ne vois pas bien pourquoi "de" n'introduirait pas l'appartenance dans les 3 cas ?

Dans le 1er cas des est l'article défini contracté de+les. Cela entendu, dans les 3 phrases de est la préposition introduisant le complément de nom.

Il ne s'agit que de la préposition « de », seulement, et il n'y a pas de notion d'article partitif dans ces groupes nominaux.
1/ L’expansion des commerces futiles. (« Des » est la contraction de « de les » ; les commerces futiles sont opposés aux autres, qui ne sont pas futiles.)
2/ L’expansion de futiles commerces. (les commerces que l'expansion concerne sont futiles ;  effacement de
« de » (expansion de de futiles commerces))
3/ L’expansion de commerces futiles.  (Dans ce cas aussi, c'est la règle de l'effacement qui détermine la forme ; « de des » devient « de » ; le sens est le même que dans « 2/ ».)
Cas d'effacement sur le modèle d'exemples tirés du Guide de grammaire française pour étudiants finnophones,
J. M. Kalmbach
Après la préposition « de », les formes d’article indéfini commençant par « d » sont ef­fa­cées :

cette envie d’    une glace.
cette envie d’    un  gâteau.
une envie de      glaces.  (« une envie de des glaces » (ne se dit jamais), indéfini)
une envie de      gâteaux.  (« une envie de des gâteaux » (ne se dit jamais), indéfini)
une envie de      glace.  (« une envie de de la glace » (ne se dit jamais), partitif)
une envie de      gâteau.  (« une envie de du (de de le) gâteau » (ne se dit jamais), partitif « du », contraction de « de le », qui ne se dit jamais)

un seau de peinture ← un seau de de la peinture [de = « où il y a »]
une feuille de papier ← une feuille de du (de de le) papier [de papier = « constitué de papier »,
Additions suite à des commentaires
Savez-vous alors pourquoi il est possible de remplacer "des" par "de" lorsque l'adjectif précède le nom qu'il qualifie ? Comment les référents dans la phrase 1 - les commerces - diffèrent-ils de ceux dans 2 et 3 ? Dans les deux cas on parle d'un nombre indéterminé de commerces futiles qui sont en expansion et cela sans qu'on ne sache le nombre des commerces non-futiles.
I
En ce qui concerne la règle du remplacement de « des » par « de » lorsque le nom est précédé d'un adjectif, il ne semblerait pas exister de véritable raison que l'on puisse citer en tant qu'explication fonctionnelle ; les grammairiens des 16e et 17e siècles se contentent de mentionner le principe, et on s'aperçoit qu'en ces périodes de l'histoire de la langue où des grammaires de plus en plus critiques sont apparues, la nature même de l'article n'était toujours pas clairement établie.
L’article indéfini dans les grammaires françaises du
17ème au début du 18ème siècle (1618 à 1747)
Point Viviane
Université de Paris-Sorbonne

1.3.2 La construction des + adjectif + substantif.
Les grammaires du 17ème au début du 18ème siècle identifient, si l’on emploie la terminologie contemporaine, une variante combinatoire de, du pluriel des, devant un adjectif. La construction des + adjectif + substantif est ainsi décrite par Maupas (1618), Oudin (1640), Chiflet (1659) et Régnier Desmarais (1706).
Maupas souligne la variation lorsque l’adjectif précède le nom à propos du pluriel de un avec des choses dont nous parlons comme d’un tout, & d’un corps intégral (Maupas, 1618 : f.23v) :

De ces mêmes choses, si nous voulions parler en pluriel de même sens, nous leur appliquerions l’article des, devant les substantifs, comme Des rois, des soucis, des
récompenses. Et l’article De, devant les adjectifs s’ils précédaient ces substantifs là, comme De bons roys, de poignants soucis, de grandes récompenses (Op. cit, f. 24r).

Chiflet fait la même remarque :

Quand l’adjectif est mis devant le substantif, au pluriel, il faut user de l’article de. Par exemple, pour le nominatif pluriel il y a de curieuses remarques en ce livre. Il y a de vaillants soldats en cette place. Au datif pluriel, j’ai donné des récompenses à de
vaillants soldats. À l’accusatif. Il m’a envoyé d’excellents livres (Chiflet, 1659 : 16).

De la même manière, selon Régnier Desmarais, l’indéfini de peut marquer « l’accusatif ou le nominatif quand le substantif est précédé de son adjectif comme dans donner de grands exemples de vertu »
(Régnier Desmarais, 1706 : 170).
Ce qui est notable à travers ces remarques, c’est que la forme de change de nature. En effet des, à part pour Port-Royal qui l’identifie comme le pluriel de l’indéfini un, une, est le pluriel du défini au cas génitif / ablatif. Dès lors, quand de remplace des, il passe de la catégorie de l’indéfini au défini : une même forme apparaît dans deux catégories distinctes. À nouveau cette analyse fragilise le cadre théorique dans lequel de est un article indéfini.

II
Le référent dans « 1/ » est déterminé par l'adjectif « futile » ; c'est à dire qu'il consiste en l'ensemble de tous les commerces qui sont futiles ; tous ces commerces sont concernés dans l'expansion dont il est question.
Dans « 2/ » et « 3/ » le référents n'est plus qu'une certaine partie (indéfinie) des commerces qui sont futiles. « De » est bien une forme de « des », l'article indéfini pluriel. Un nombre de commerces non futiles est  totalement sans conséquence dans un tel contexte, à moins qu'il y ait une relation dont on veuille parler.

Il ne s'occupait qu'à  de futiles commerces qui lui permettaient de subvenir à peine à ses besoins personnels.

Dans cette communauté de futiles commerces s'établissent  assez facilement, mais assez souvent ils n'ont pas la vie longue.

C'était une rue commerçante, une de ces rues où  de futiles commerces, en plus grand nombre que dans les autres rues, proposaient à la population des plats à emporter  ou à consommer sur place et de l'habillement. (Dans ce cas, on mentionne que les commerces non futiles se trouvent comparativement en petit nombre, mais il n'y a aucune nécessité de dire cela.)



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Dans les trois phrases suivantes, quelle est la fonction de "de" ?


L'expansion des commerces futiles.

It is said this way, with plural des instead of de, although if you don’t want the partitive article des, you would need to restructure the sentence.

L'expansion de futiles commerces.

You could say it this way, because the function of de is before an adjective modifying a noun.  futiles is a Regular Adjective in abstract position.

L'expansion de commerces futiles.

You could say it this way, and the function of "de" is la préposition between two nouns.  Because L'expansion isn’t considered a quantifier (le quantificateur, masculin), the second noun is diminished by only the preposition (la préposition de, feminine).  And then because neither L'expansion nor commerces (without the adjective) indicate diminishment, this is why the partitive article would generally be used (as in the first sentence), not the preposition de.      If you wanted to keep the preposition de between the two nouns, then it necessarily diminishes the second noun commerces, which could be the intended meaning, or not.
